# Regexp for html

Tags: php, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have the following string:

```
$str = " 
<li>r</li>  
<li>a</li>  
<li>n</li>  
<li>d</li>  
...
<li>om</li>  
";
```

How do I get the HTML for the first n-th `<li>` tags?

```
Ex : n = 3 ; result = "<li>r<...>n</li>;
```

I would like a regexp if possible.

Comment: [rant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: All you need to know can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Why all the downvoting? Most newbies *will* make this mistake once (and hopefully only once). Also, OP isn't parsing entire documents, it looks like it's a string of unnested `<li></li>` tags. Not a great place to use regex, but it isn't *that* bad either.

Comment: prodigitalson - actually you gave me the best answer I could hope for...how was I supposed to find that just by searching ?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - Agreed. This is a valid question that deserves an answer. That being said, I am going home to play with my son :)

Comment: This question has been asked soooo many times. Are people not searching? Is it not coming up properly in searches? What is going on? It's been asked at least few times just this afternoon!

Comment: @webbiedave: OP is not parsing an HTML documents with regex, OP is searching a string with only one type of tag, all at the same level (no nesting - which is usually the main problem with regex + HTML). Not really the same.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: How is there no nesting? His inner html is spelling the word "random" which leads me to believe that anything could be in those tags.

Comment: @webbiedavie: It's a very specific sort of example and he never says "any HTMl" or "other tags an' stuff" which leads me to think he will stick to the example (or similar strings); but fair enough: if OP shows that his other input strings can have nested tags, you get 100 internet points and I'll delete my earlier comment. :)

Answer (score 10):

Like this.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($str);
$x = new DOMXPath($dom); 

// we wan the 4th node.
foreach($x->query("//li[4]") as $node) 
{
  echo $node->c14n()
}
```

Oh yeah, learn [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp), it will save you lots of trouble in the future.

Comment: I would always recommend SimpleXML over DOMDocument dor so simple things as DOMDocument needs an overload of additional objects (like for xpath) and makes selecting of elements and their content way to complicated.

Comment: @Kau-Boy - interesting, care to post an example? Also do realize DOMDocument doesn't require you run the html though tidy. That in itself is a major win for me.

Answer (score 6):

The Solution of @Byron but with SimpleXML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

foreach($xml->xpath("//li[4]") as $node){
  echo $node[0]; // The first element is the text node
}
```

**EDIT**: Another reason I really like at simplexml is the easy debugging of the content of a node. You can just use print_r($xml) to print the object with it's child nodes.

Comment: Corrected, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure you are aware it is not a good idea to use regular expressions to work through HTML unless you were to "tidy" it first.

A very viable solution in PHP would be to navigate the HTML structure using Simple XML (http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or as a DOM Document (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).